# Compiler errors using python -m pip install with numpy (for tensorflow object detection) on Windows

Tags: python, pip, object-detection

I am using Windows 10 and I have anaconda and python version 3.9.0 installed. I am trying to install the object-detection API from https://github.com/tensorflow/models to perform face detection. I cloned the repository successfully but when I try to install all the required dependencies using `python -m pip install`, only a few of them are installed and then the entire terminal window is filled with errors in red font. How do I resolve this? I tried upgrading pip but I am getting the same errors. Please help.

! ([Here you can see the image of the terminal with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYscB.png))

```
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcnumpy\linalg\lapack_lite\f2c.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite\f2c.obj
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:build\temp.win-amd64-3.9 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64 npymath.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__umath_linalg build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\linalg\umath_linalg.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite\python_xerbla.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite\f2c_z_lapack.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite\f2c_c_lapack.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite\f2c_d_lapack.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite\f2c_s_lapack.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite\f2c_lapack.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite\f2c_blas.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite\f2c_config.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite\f2c.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp39-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp39-win_amd64.lib
      building 'numpy.random.mtrand' extension
      compiling C sources
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\random
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\random\mtrand
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNPY_NEEDS_MINGW_TIME_WORKAROUND -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcnumpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.obj
      mtrand.c
      numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(35419): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'long', possible loss of data
      numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(35429): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'long', possible loss of data
      numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(35496): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'long', possible loss of data
      numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(36796): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
      numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(36980): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
      numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(37143): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
      numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(40343): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
      numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(40400): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(42673): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
      numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(42689): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
      error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNPY_NEEDS_MINGW_TIME_WORKAROUND -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcnumpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.obj" failed with exit status 2
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\KIIT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0bspjxl6\\numpy_e779b263f09e4f25ab046d92cb613e1d\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\KIIT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0bspjxl6\\numpy_e779b263f09e4f25ab046d92cb613e1d\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kh160ac8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6m4j9ruk\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6m4j9ruk\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6m4j9ruk\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython >= 0.29' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version<'"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' setuptools setuptools_scm wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Is there an easier way to install and use the object-detection API?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: There were a lot of error messages. So I copy pasted a part of it now.

Comment: try  using tensorflow recommended python. as python 3.9 is new some packages may not work

Comment: Also make sure the version of the C compiler matches the one used by upstream. Since each Python version has a canonical C compiler version on Windows, changing your Python version (and using the right compiler for that different version) may be all you need.

Comment: @user13966865 Installing python 3.7.7 worked.